# Visual Basic - Counting total user input of a character

Tags: vb.net

I am currently learning programming in college using Visual Basic hence I am still a beginner and still not know many functions. Can someone please show me how to do this, I am really confused.

> Adapt the programme so that when the user enters "N" the programme displays "The number of diamonds entered is :" and the number of diamonds

Basically, count the amount of times Y is entered when the user inputs N. It's hard to explain, here is the code which I have to adapt:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim Weight As Integer
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the weight of your diamond in grams")
    Weight = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("This diamond costs : " & Weight * 350)
    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to price another Y/N?")
    Dim UserValue As Char = Console.ReadLine
    If UserValue = "Y" Then
        While UserValue = "Y"
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the weight of the new diamond in grams")
            Weight = Console.ReadLine
            Console.WriteLine("This diamond costs : " & Weight * 350)
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to price another Y/N?")
            Console.ReadLine()
        End While
    End If
    UserValue = "N"
    Console.WriteLine("The total number of diamonds entered is : ")
End Sub
```

Comment: if you already copy/pasted answer, please delete your question

Comment: You need to declare a variable to count the number of times the user enters "Y" and add one to it each time, then display it

Comment: There are also several bugs in that code which you will need to fix first.

Answer (score -1):

What I'd do is dim an integer, eg, `y` to count how many Y's and assign the following when the user returns "Y"

```
y = y + 1
```

So that when the user finally gives an "N" you say

```
Console.WriteLine(y)
```

In simple terms.